# Android camera API used to capture image and video record

Tags: android

**I have created an app using camera2 API but it is not supported in Kitkat Version I searched and found its the latest API developed for devices <=21**

I want to make my app supported to both the devices having API >= 21 and also to devices having API < 21 , Is there something I can do in my app .....??

Comment: use deprecated camera api class for lower version and latest for higher version

Comment: camera2 also works on KitKat most of the time but just being lack of some advanced features (and some embedded problems such as in flash light stuff)

Comment: @JanKaufmann: "camera2 also works on KitKat" -- the `android.hardware.camera2.*` classes are not part of the Android SDK until Android 5.0.

Comment: Ooops.. Somehow I mistakenly thought that Kitkat is under android 5.0

Comment: @Prashant Sharma can u write the deprecated code here to use API for both lower and higher version

Comment: Ok does the camera app effect the if kitkat is upgraded to lollipop ?? Actually in my inbuilt firm having 5.0 my app working nicely but the device which is been upgraded from lower to 5.0 are having stretched preview of camera .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this lib,Support is from API 14

https://github.com/google/cameraview